# How to create multilines legend in Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio

In Data Studio my 10 points pie chart is like below:

[image]

As you can see there is a navigation arrow in the legend at the top of the pie.

I wonder how can I avoid the navigation by creating the multiline legend? How can I wrap the current single line legend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three ways to display all items in the legend; located in the *Style* Tab of the [Pie Chart](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7187587) (added a GIF to elaborate):

> 1. Increasing the max lines;
> 2. Increasing the width of the Pie Chart;
> 3. Reducing the font size of the legend.

[image: 2]]

**EDIT: Multi line Legend (Workaround using a Bar Chart)**
How about using the legend from a Bar Chart? Added a GIF to elaborate as well as a few points:

- ***Bar Chart***: Use a Dimension and Breakdown Dimension that's the same as the one on the Pie Chart and enable the legend (Top) as well as using 2 lines (no legend for the Pie Chart)
- ***Shape***: Add a Shape over the Bar Chart (one that blends in with the background)
- ***Order***: Right click on components and select *Order* from the drop down to change the order of the components (*Bar Chart*: Send to back; *Shape*: Send Backwards (behind the Pie Chart); *Pie Chart*: Bring to Front)
- ***Fine Tuning***: Use Shift + Movement for precision placement (to get the shape exactly where you want it)

[image: 3]]